# Not getting the desired output during api call due to asycnronous programming inexperience

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

I want to talk out the distinct values from the object.But due to less exprerience in asyncronous programming i'm stuck. This is the methods

```
gameSchema.methods.computeBets = async function(callback){
    const game = this;
    try {
        const { gameType } = game;
        let model = Schema;
        gameType === 'Fast Parity' ? model = FastParity : model = SlowParity;
        const gameDetails = await model.findOne({ gameId: game._id });
        const { allPlayerBetted } = gameDetails;
        let color = {};
        let number = {};
        allPlayerBetted.forEach(async (bet) => {
            const betdetails = await UserBet.findById(bet._id);
            const { colorBettedOn, numberBettedOn, amountBettedOnColor, amountBettedOnNumber } = betdetails;
            console.log(colorBettedOn, numberBettedOn, amountBettedOnColor, amountBettedOnNumber);
            if (!color.colorBettedOn)
                color[colorBettedOn] = amountBettedOnColor;
            else
                color.colorBettedOn += amountBettedOnColor;
            if (!number.numberBettedOn)
                number[numberBettedOn] = amountBettedOnNumber;
            else
                number.numberBettedOn += amountBettedOnNumber;
        });
        callback(color, number);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
  
    }
  }
```

And this is the api call:

```
router.post('/game/computeBets/:id', async(req, res)=> {
    try {
        const game = await Game.findById(req.params.id);
       await game.computeBets((color,number)=>console.log(color,number));
        // console.log(game);
        res.send();
    } catch (error)
    {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send();
    }
})
```

Now when calling this api i'm getting this output:
{} {}
voilet 3 29 49
voilet 3 29 49
voilet 3 29 49

i have tried many things but nothing worked. Help with the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really use `forEach` with `await`, you would instead want to change:

```
allPlayerBetted.forEach(async (bet) => {
  // ...
});
```

to

```
await Promise.all(allPlayerBetted.map(async (bet) => {
  // ...
}));
```

To explain, when you have

```
allPlayerBetted.forEach(async (bet) => {
    // ...
    return
});
```

this is equivalent to

```
allPlayerBetted.forEach((bet) => {
    return new Promise();
});
```

but nothing is actually waiting for the promise to resolve.  What you want to get back is an array of the promises:

```
allPlayerBetted.map((bet) => {
    return new Promise();
});
```

and then you can wait for all of them to resolve by using `Promise.all`

```
await Promise.all(allPlayerBetted.map((bet) => {
    return new Promise();
}));
```

and then if you want to await inside:

```
await Promise.all(allPlayerBetted.map(async (bet) => {
    await somePromise();
    return;
}));
```

and you get to what you want.

Comment: can you please explain a little more

Comment: i have applied and its working fine but what is promiseall and .map function. And where ot use it

Comment: i want to add the values of distinct keys like in this we have
voilet 3 29 49
voilet 3 29 49
voilet 3 29 49 now i want {voilet:9,29:147}